# How to create a for loop based lightbox gallery with django

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

(Newbie Django dev here, with no Javascript knowledge)

I'm building a Django website designed to display one page for each *notice* in the db.
Some images can be attached to the notices: sometimes none, sometimes a few, up to maximum a dozen.

I'd like to display these images on top of the detail.html page, following the example shown here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_lightbox.asp

I understood that I need to adapt the code to use a *for* loop. I did my best to adapt it but I'm stuck with a non working gallery.

Here is my code right now, adapted from the tutorial:

detail.html:

```
<div id="illustrations" class="galerie">

  {% for image in object.illustration_objet_archi.all %}

  <div class="row">

    <div class="column">

      <img src="{{ image.image_thumbnail.url }}" onclick="openModal();currentSlide({{ forloop.counter }})" class="hover-shadow">

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- The Modal/Lightbox -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
    
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="mySlides">
        <div class="numbertext"> {{ forloop.counter }} / {{ image.image.count }} </div>
        <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <!-- Next/previous controls -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

      <!-- Caption text -->
      <div class="caption-container">
        <p id="caption">{{ image.legende }}</p>
      </div>

      <!-- Thumbnail image controls -->
      <div class="column">
        <img class="demo" src="{{ image.image.url }}" onclick="currentSlide({{ forloop.counter }})">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  {% endfor %}

</div>
```

style.css (the body refers to a text area following the gallery):

```
body {
  font: 16px/1.5em "Overpass", "Open Sans", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.galerie {
  width: 80%;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/* Create four equal columns that floats next to eachother */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 900px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Hide the slides by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Caption text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

img.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

lightbox.js:

```
// Open the Modal
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

// Close the Modal
function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);a
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is in wrong div. You only need a image to be in loop so use loop only outside a img tag where you need dynamic image. Can you try replacing your detail.html code with the following code.

```
<div id="illustrations" class="galerie">

<div class="row">

{% for image in object.illustration_objet_archi.all %}
<div class="column">
    <img src="{{ image.image_thumbnail.url }}" onclick="openModal();currentSlide({{ forloop.counter }})" class="hover-shadow">
</div>
{% endfor %}

</div>

<!-- The Modal/Lightbox -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>

<div class="modal-content">

{% for image in object.illustration_objet_archi.all %}
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext"> {{ forloop.counter }} / {{ image.image.count }} </div>
    <img src="{{ image.image.url }}" style="width:100%">
  </div>
{% endfor %}

  <!-- Next/previous controls -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

  <!-- Caption text -->
  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption">{{ image.legende }}</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Thumbnail image controls -->
{% for image in object.illustration_objet_archi.all %}
  <div class="column">
    <img class="demo" src="{{ image.image.url }}" onclick="currentSlide({{ forloop.counter }})">
  </div>
{% endfor %}

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Prabin, it's much better now indeed! The loop works. However there are still some display glitches: the  thumbnail images in the row don't adapt their width as they should, they overlap when the window width is reduced. Also, when the modal windows opens there's a big mess of images under the focused image. Could it be related to the javascript? I didn't modify the original one. Maybe I need to make the it aware of the loop one way or another?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, the issue is not because of JS. There are some changes you need to do in html itself add style="width:100%" in all img tag and at last  <!-- Thumbnail image controls --> add also alt for img tag and remove a at the end of semicolon in JS plusSlides function.